# Azure Devops Browserstack integration - BrowserStackResults task - Unexpected "Build not found by name" error

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, browserstack

Trying to set up Azure Devops pipeline for test automation run  (Java + Maven + Selenium) tests are running on Browserstack

To view Browser Stack Results I added two tasks BrowserStackConfig and BrowserStackResults to pipiline YAML file
(according to [instructions from BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/azure-pipelines#configure-browserstack-local-in-azure-pipelines))

But I am getting unexpected error on BrowserStackResults step : 'Build not found by name ..'

[image: Error]

Now I am trying to get results for "old" automation run on BS (Set BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_NAME to existing BS results = 20220114_666666)

Setup:
Using Azure Devops with installed Browserstack extension

Steps:

1. Prepared YML file

[image: Prepared YML file]

2. Add pipeline for YML
3. Run pipeline

Result:

BS Configuration step works

[image: Config pass]

Unexpected error on BrowserStackResults step "##[error] Build not found by name: "20220114_666666" error

Answer (score 0):

The following only fixes BrowserStackConfig task:

```
variables:
- name: BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_NAME
  value: "test-001"
```

But not for BrowserStackResults task. Is there another environment variable that controls the later? Or a list of variables used by browserstack?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Browserstack

> **Note**: Ensure to set the `build` capability in your test script using the environment variable `BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_NAME`. The extension will fail to embed test reports in your pipeline if this capability is missing.

**Set variables for BrowserStack Azure DevOps Extension**

The BrowserStack Azure DevOps extension, by default, sets the following environment variables:

```
BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME
BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY
BROWSERSTACK_LOCAL
BROWSERSTACK_LOCAL_IDENTIFIER
BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_NAME
```

When you create a service connection, the `BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME` and the `BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY` are automatically added as variables during the configuration step.

The extension also adds the `BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_NAME` variable that autogenerates a build name for your test runs.

**Edit your test script to call environment variables**

Edit your test script to add the environment variables for setting capabilities using the following code snippets:

```
String buildName = System.getenv("BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_NAME");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("build", buildName); // CI/CD job name using BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_NAME env variable
```

Seems you need to check your code if  `BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_NAME` environment variable value is passed to `buildName` and added to capabilities. Otherwise, the report won't be generated

Answer (score -1):

In fact, your CI script lacks the necessary step to actually run the tests. That's why BrowserStack reports no build with that name.

Your job contains uploading app and publishing results while there are no tests had been executed in between. In other words, you didn't launch any tests and you are asking for test results.

To resolve this, you should include the script responsible for launching the tests as "Script" step in your job. (Same script you use in your terminal to launch your tests with your automation framework)

Check this screenshot:
[azure-pipline-steps-overview-with-robot-framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcW0U.png)

If, for instance, you're working with Python, Robot Framework, and Appium, the following command can be used:

```
  - script: |
    browserstack-sdk robot --include Minor Tests/.
  displayName: Launching Automated Tests
```

In addition, if you don't have the link of your app in your code you can configure the BrowserstackAppUploader. In this way you can commit and push your build and the BS plugin will handle it:

```
- task: BrowserStackAppUploader@0
inputs:
  appPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Resources/app/app.apk'
```

Now, the entire pipeline code would look something like this:

```
trigger:
- main
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
jobs:
- job: RunTests
  displayName: 'Run Tests on BrowserStack'
  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.9'  # Use the version of Python you need        
  - script: |
      pip install -r requirements.txt
    displayName: 'Install Dependencies'
  - task: BrowserStackConfig@0
    inputs:
      BrowserStackServiceEndPoint: 'IDFM BrowserStack Connection'
  - task: BrowserStackAppUploader@0
    inputs:
      appPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Resources/app/app.apk'
  - script: |
      browserstack-sdk robot --include Minor Tests/.
    displayName: Launching Automated Tests
  - task: BrowserStackResults@1
    inputs:
      BrowserStackServiceEndPoint: 'IDFM BrowserStack Connection'
  - task: BrowserStackAppUploader@0
    inputs:
      appPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Resources/app/app.apk'
  - script: |
      browserstack-sdk robot --include Minor Tests/.
    displayName: Launching Automated Tests
  - task: BrowserStackResults@1
    inputs:
      browserstackProduct: 'App Automate'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to take some time to familiarise yourself with the site's rules, including the one that [bans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) so-called "AI" generated content.

Comment: I have faced the same issue, and after resolving it I decided to share the solution. I have used AI to correct the paragraph, please make a look on the screenshot as well as the CI code.. it takes few seconds to understand that the code is generated by human.. 
thanks !  @miken32

Comment: From the link I posted: “This includes "asking" the question to an AI generator then copy-pasting its output as well as using an AI generator to "reword" your answers.”